# Is there a convention which fields are reserved for implementation in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I read the documentation of `threading.Thread` that mentions:

> There are two ways to specify the activity: by passing a callable object to the constructor, or by overriding the run() method in a subclass

I have written the following program to test it:

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._started = False
    def run(self):
        self._started = True
obj = MyThread()
obj.start()
obj.join()
print(self._started)
```

However it fails:

```
$ python3 ./1.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/./1.py", line 10, in <module>
    obj.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 951, in start
    if self._started.is_set():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'is_set'
```

The documentation does not mention that "_started" is used internally for threading.Thread.

What should I expect from such a python program? Should I expect that all undocumented attributes of `threading.Thread` will start with a leading `_` and when inheriting from `threading.Thread` I should not make any fields with `_`? Finally, which attributes are safe to set and which are not?

Comment: I don't think there's any such convention, this is just poor design. Python provides a way to create private attributes with `__` prefix. A class that's intended to be subclassed should do that.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-single-and-double-underscore-before-an-object-name

Comment: Linters that I've used (the defaults bundled with VSCode and PyCharm) treat a leading single underscore as `protected`, which translate to C++/Java/C# as "accessible to methods within a class and its subclasses, but not from outside". I would follow this convention. A leading double underscore is conventionally treated as `private` (only available within the class, not subclasses).